# How to get HResult from an exception in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I thought this would be a simple task.  In my Silverlight application, I am catching an `IOException` (in this particular case, I want to show a message to the user when they try to save a file that is already open in another application).  I figured I'd find out the `HResult` of this exception and display a localized message to the user.

Unfortunately, `Exception.HResult` is `protected` in Silverlight (I am using Silverlight 5).  Thus, I cannot access the `HResult` of the exception I am interested in.

I also found [`Marshal.GetHRForException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.gethrforexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but this method is `internal` in Silverlight (despite the MSDN documentation).  I've found evidence suggesting that this method can be called from a trusted application, but my application will not be running as a trusted application.

How can I differentiate between different `IOException` that may occur?  Am I stuck showing one generic error message for any `IOException` that may occur?

I have found a surprisingly small amount of information on this and am having trouble moving forward.

I guess I should note that on my development machine, I get a nice, descriptive error message when I try to save to a file that is open in another application.  However, on a machine without the Silverlight SDK installed, I get a message stating that the debugging resource strings are unavailable.

Comment: You can use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().  Last paragraph very strongly suggests that you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the reply.  That method can be used by trusted applications only.  I get a `MethodAccessException` when I try to call it.  You mention that maybe I am trying to solve the wrong problem.  My application will be used in many languages, so I have translated string resource files.  I would like to let the user know, in this case, that the file they are trying to write to is in use by another application.  I need this error message to be in the user's selected language.